# How do I clear text on shell?

Tags: python

I need to clear the IDLE shell, using code. The only way I know of to remove the text is closing the shell and reopening. I want this to be able to put into code that requires refreshing the shell, for example a memory game, giving a string of words, and then removing them, or some kind of animation made of text pictures.

Essentially I want to do something like `shell.clear()` or something similarly easy to use. It can be a function or whatever, but I'd like it to be easy to put into some preexisting code.

I do not know if such a thing is possible, but if you have any pointers, tips or code, I'd appreciate the help.

IDLE 3.7.3 on Mac.

Comment: Does `CTRL L` work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from os import system

#for windows
system('cls')

#for Unix based systems
system('clear')
```

Or if you are inside IDLE or Python interpreter you can use this function:

```
def cls(): print ("\n" * 100)
```

That you can call `cls()` whenever you need to clear your screen.

Comment: I tried both of them (even though is Mac) and it did not work. There were no errors, but it just didn't do anything. I copy-pasted (no typos), printed something beforehand, and when I ran it, the printed thing stayed.

Comment: @AidanTung Are you inside the python interpreter?

Comment: I do not know what that is, I am in the "put code here" window that is not the shell. The terminal? I don't know what it is called.

Comment: The OP already said they're using the IDLE shell; neither of those apply to IDLE, which isn't based on `cmd.exe` or a UNIX-style terminal/shell.

Comment: ```def cls(): print ("\n" * 100)``` use this function and call it whenever you need it

Comment: @IsmailElMoudni It would be best if you put that in your answer.

Comment: @IsmailElMoudni If I did this, I would still be able to scroll up and see. The point here is to wipe it, not go down.